# Taking Average of Certain Columns while keeping certain columns untouched

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I am looking to take the average of certain columns, and then renaming the first 2 columns to make a brand new data frame.

Lets say this is DF

| Participant | Date | Score1 | Place | Job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | 10_Sep_Mon | 12 | 3 | 5.5 |
| Second | 10_Sep_Mon | 11 | 2 | 5.7 |
| Third | 10_Sep_Mon | 14 | 2.5 | 5 |
| Fourth | 10_Sep_Mon | 21 | 2.8 | 5.1 |

I want to make a new data frame that looks like this, where the first column name is named different, the date is kept the same, and all columns starting the 3rd and until the very end ncol(DF), cause there are lots of columns than 3.

This would be a new data frame called DF2

| Participant | Date | Score1 | Place | Job |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Averaged | 10_Sep_Mon | 14.5 | 2.6 | 5.3 |

What is the best way to apply this calculation?

Here is some code if that may help. Thank you!

```
Participant <- c("First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth")
Date <- c("10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon", "10_Sep_Mon")
Score1 <- c(12, 11, 14, 21)
Place <- c(3, 2, 2.5, 2.8)
Job <- c(5.5, 5.7, 5, 5.1)
DF <- data.frame(Participant, Date, Score1, Place, Job)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cbind` first row, first two columns to the `colMeans` of the remaining columns (need to be `t`ransposed).

```
cbind(DF[1, 1:2], t(colMeans(DF[-(1:2)])))
#   Participant       Date Score1 Place   Job
# 1       First 10_Sep_Mon   14.5 2.575 5.325
```

Answer (score 2):

Or using `dplyr` you could do:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

DF %>%
  group_by(Participant = "Averaged", Date) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), mean), .groups = "drop")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 5
#>   Participant Date       Score1 Place   Job
#>   <chr>       <chr>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Averaged    10_Sep_Mon   14.5  2.58  5.32
```